# How can I get forward this terminal interface?

Tags: command-line, nano

I'm working on a project based on installing a server FTP on Amazon Web Services. I'm doing it through Ubuntu 16.04. No such a matter, everything is doing good so far.

But I got stuck in a step that requires me to type some commands to modify a specific file. I actually typed the commands, but I don't know what to press to save changes and get on the next step. I tried pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, but nothing seems to happen. Does anyone have a clue?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/JuadkPW.png]

Comment: ctrl+o as it clearly states at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

The editor that you are using is `nano`

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to write the file, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit.

Comment: For even deeper learning on nano see the [Nano Command Manual](https://nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.html)

Comment: In general, the bottom of the screen in `nano` has the basic commands. `^` means `Ctrl`.